# If two non-equivalent representations are irreducible then sum is 0

Tags: representation-theory

We have a finite group and two representations $D_1:G\to GL_n(\mathbb{C}),D_2:G\to GL_m(\mathbb{C})$ for some positive integers $m,n$. We define

$$T=\sum_{g\in G}D_1(g)BD_2(g^{-1})$$
where $B\in M_{n\times m}(\mathbb{C})$.

The first question asked to show that $D_1(h)T=TD_2(h)$ for any $h\in G$, which is fine.

The next part, which I am having difficulty with, is:

*Assume that $D_1,D_2$ are non-equivalent irreducible representations (this means the corresponding modules of $D_1$ and $D_2$ are non-isomorphic and simple). Prove that $T=0$.*

I'm not sure what it means exactly by "the corresponding modules of D_i". Does this just mean $D_i(G)$? (Is that a module?)

Comment: A complex representation of a finite group $G$ is the same thing as a $\mathbb{C}[G]$-module, where $\mathbb{C}[G]$ denotes the group algebra.

Comment: Right not you have $D_i$ as a homomorphism to a general linear group, the corresponding module is just the vector space which that general linear group acts on along with the data of how $G$ acts.

Comment: OK, thanks, I can visualise that now. So how do I go about proving that $T=0$? My first thought was that $T$ lies in both these modules, but their intersection must be $\{0\}$ since they are non-isomorphic and simple, but I don't think this is the case ($T\in M_{n\times m}(\mathbb{C})$ and not $M_n(\mathbb{C})$ or $M_n(\mathbb{C})$).

Comment: Are you familiar with Schur's lemma?

Comment: Yes. So, as $T$ is a map from the module of $D_2$ to the module of $D_1$, it must be the zero map?